# Anyone of two textfield validation

Tags: javascript

I have a forgot password form. It has two fields 1) email and 2) mobile. So what I need is a validation for it. like both field should not be empty, both field should not be filled, any one only should be filled. email should be in email format and mobile should only contain numbers.

javascript Code:

```
function validate_fgtmgrpwd(){
  var adminid=document.f_mgr_password.mgrid;
  var adminmobile=document.f_mgr_password.mgrmobile;
  var mgr_length=document.f_mgr_password.mgrmobile.value;

  if ((document.f_mgr_password.mgrid=="Ex: ManagerID@Email.com")||
  (document.f_mgr_password.mgrid==""))
    {}
    {document.getElementById("validationMessage").innerHTML="&nbsp;<font color='#FF0000'>Error: </font> Please Enter Either Email Id Or Mobile No:!";
  popup('validationPopup');
    mgrid.focus();
    return false; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the validation server side, not client side. There are always ways to get around your javascript form validation.

So you should check/validate the POST values in your php script, and act accordingly.

Comment: But it's good to have at client side as well to avoid multiple page redirects or page load..

Answer (score 0):

With html5 you can define an input type="email" for your email field ( so it parse properly inserted email ) and an input type="tel" for your mobile phone field. So, set the clear field at onfocus event for the other field. this should works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function validate_fgtmgrpwd() {
    var adminid = document.f_mgr_password.mgrid,
        adminmobile = document.f_mgr_password.mgrmobile,
        emailExp = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/gi,
        phoneExp = /^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$/gi;

    if(!adminid.value.length && !adminmobile.value.length){
        alert("At Least one field is mandatory!");
        adminid.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        if(adminid.value.length && !emailExp.test(adminid.value)){
            alert("Enter a valid email");
            adminid.focus();
            return false;
        } else if(adminmobile.value.length && !phoneExp.test(adminmobile.value)) {
            alert("Enter a valid phone number");
            adminmobile.focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

For HTML5 supporting browsers, native validation will work and for other browsers, custom validation will work.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MR6bD/2/